# Sonarqube Quality Gate status link in Azure devops Pull Request always points to localhost

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarqube-scan

The Quality gate status url in a PR is always pointing to localhost and not to the actual sonarqube server.
The detailed analysis report link in the build pipeline is working fine.
SonarQube 8.2 Enterprise Edition, Scanner Latest from Azure Devops Marketplace.
Create a PR request and trigger a Build with Sonar Analysis.
Add a Build policy to validate Sonar Quality Gate Click on the link.
It routes to localhost and not the actual server.

[image]

When I click on “Quality Gate failed” hyperlink, it takes me to http://localhost/dashboard?id=***&pullRequest=952.
Ideally it should point to the server where I have my sonarqube hosted.

Answer (score 2):

I found the resolution for this we need to go into **Administration > General > Server base URL** update the '*Server base URL*'. on sonarqube portal.

Comment: :) not yet. To accept an answer, click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons. It should be green.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following has been configured in SonarQube:

sonar.core.serverBaseURL is set to the base url of SonarQube including the port number.

> Also double check if your proxy firewall which block the request from
>   the SonarQube server to TFS.
>
> Try to add your TFS server host name in “http.nonProxyHosts” in your
>   “sonar.properties” file.

Otherwise, this may related to your TFS version. Try to upgrade to TFS 2018.Update3.2 and above.

More details take a look at this similar question:  [TFS Pull Request Decoration Not Working](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/tfs-pull-request-decoration-not-working/8713/1)

Comment: I am not managing any sonar.properties file, I have updated the parameter in advance settings:
sonar.core.serverBaseURL=$(sonarUrl)
still it is pointing to me to localhost